# Starting Android application at boot completion: is my solution overly complicated?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an application that I would like to have automatically start following boot completion. The following code seems overly complicated and I get erratic application starts when swiping to a neighbouring workspace.

What am I missing here? I have an activity class, a service class, as well as a broadcast receiver. Below is my code (in that order) followed by the manifest.

```
public class BlueDoor extends Activity implements OnClickListener{  
Button btnExit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnExit = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ExitButton);  
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(this);
}   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ExitButton:
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
 }
}
```

service.class

```
 public class BlueDoorStartService extends Service {
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
  callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
  callIntent.setClass(this, BlueDoor.class);
  startActivity(callIntent); 
  // do something when the service is created
 }
}
```

broadcast receiver

```
public class StartBlueDoorAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BlueDoorStartService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
 }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bluedoor"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver 
    android:name=".StartBlueDoorAtBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

    <service android:name=".BlueDoorStartService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".BlueDoor"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**UPDATE Solution(s), 10/22/2015:**

Changing the service to:

```
public class BlueDoorStartService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");   
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

and the receiver to:

```
public class StartBlueDoorAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Start Service On Boot Start Up
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BlueDoorStartService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        //Start App On Boot Start Up
        Intent App = new Intent(context, BlueDoor.class);
        App.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(App);
   }
}
```

resulted in a working configuration using a service w/no misbehaving. **However** deleting the service all together and modifying the receiver thus:

```
public class StartBlueDoorAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent App = new Intent(context, BlueDoor.class);
        App.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(App);
}
}
```

also resulted in a functional as well as a more concise configuration that starts the application following boot completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BroadcastReceiver calls

> `context.startService(serviceIntent)`

so the service will be created if it doesn't exist yet (which will be the case shortly after booting) and thus start the activity from its `onCreate()` method. So the app works, to a certain extent.

BUT when you call `startService()`, the system always calls the service's `onStartCommand()` method. You did not override that method, so the system uses the standard implementation from class `android.app.Service`.

As you can read on [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/app/Service.java#Service), the method will return a value like `START_STICKY` by default. This tells the system to keep the service alive until it is explicitly stopped.

In your case, I suppose the system reacted to the swiping by temporarily killing and then reanimating (= creating) the service, which in turn started your activity.

Some information on the service lifecycle can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

**What you can do:**
Override `onStartCommand()` to start the activity from there instead of from `onCreate()`. Then use `stopSelf(int)` like described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping)

One last thing: when exiting from the activity, don't use `System.exit(0)` but call `finish()` instead, see this SO answer for ["why"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238).